# Dropzone element is not initializing

Tags: laravel-blade, vite, laravel-10

I'm still learning the new way Laravel is attaching recourses using Vite. I have the same dropzone working on another page, but it's not working on this page, and I can't figure out why. All I see on the page is the Dropzone Fallback element.

Here is the blade template with Dropzone.

```php
@extends('layouts.app', ['page_title' => 'New Fax'])

@section('content')
    <!-- Start Content-->
    <div class="container-fluid">

        <!-- start page title -->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">
                <div class="page-title-box">
                    <div class="page-title-right">
                        <ol class="breadcrumb m-0">
                            <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="{{ route('faxes.index') }}">Virtual Fax Machines</a></li>
                            <li class="breadcrumb-item active">New Fax</li>
                        </ol>
                    </div>
                    <h4 class="page-title">New Fax</h4>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- end page title -->

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">
                <div class="card mt-3">
                    <div class="card-body">



                        <div class="tab-content">

                            <!-- Body Content-->
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-lg-12">

                                    <form method="POST" id="new_fax_form" action="{{ route('faxes.sendFax') }}">
                                        @csrf

            

                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-4">
                                                <div class="mb-3">
                                                    <label for="recipient" class="form-label me-1">Add Fax Recipient <span
                                                            class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                                                    <a href="#" data-bs-toggle="popover" data-bs-placement="bottom"
                                                        data-bs-trigger="focus" title="How to format your fax number?"
                                                        data-bs-content="Enter your number as follows: area code + number.
                                                    For example: the number 1 323-212-6688 should be entered as 3232126688">
                                                        <i class="uil uil-info-circle"></i>
                                                    </a>

                                                    <input class="form-control" type="text"
                                                        placeholder="Enter a fax number" id="recipient" name="recipient" />
                                                    <div class="text-danger recipient_err error_message"></div>
                                                </div>

                                            </div>
                                        </div> <!-- end row -->


                                                <!-- File Upload -->
                                                <form action="{{ route('extensions.import') }}" method="post"
                                                    class="dropzone" id="file_dropzone" data-plugin="dropzone"
                                                    data-previews-container="#file-previews"
                                                    data-upload-preview-template="#uploadPreviewTemplate"
                                                    data-auto-process-queue="false" data-upload-multiple="false"
                                                    data-parallel-uploads="5" data-max-filesize="5" data-max-files="1"
                                                    data-thumbnail-width="200" data-accepted-files=".csv,.xls,.xlsx">
                                                    <div class="fallback">
                                                        <input name="file" type="file" multiple />
                                                    </div>

                                                    <div class="dz-message needsclick dropzone-select">
                                                        <i class="h1 text-muted mdi mdi-cloud-upload-outline"></i>
                                                        <h3>Drop files here or click to upload.</h3>
                                                        <div class="mb-1"><a
                                                                class="dropzone-select btn btn-sm btn-primary me-2">Browse
                                                                files</a>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <span class="text-muted font-13">Supported file types: .csv, .xls,
                                                            .xlsx</span>

                                                    </div>
                                                </form>

                                                <!-- Preview -->
                                                <div class="dropzone-previews mt-3" id="file-previews"></div>

                                                <!-- file preview template -->
                                                <div class="d-none" id="uploadPreviewTemplate">
                                                    <div class="card mt-1 mb-0 shadow-none border">
                                                        <div class="p-2">
                                                            <div class="row align-items-center">
                                                                <div class="col-auto">
                                                                    <div class="avatar-sm">
                                                                        <span
                                                                            class="avatar-title bg-light text-secondary rounded">
                                                                            <i class="h1 mdi mdi-file-outline "></i>
                                                                        </span>
                                                                    </div>
                                                                </div>
                                                                <div class="col ps-0">
                                                                    <a href="javascript:void(0);"
                                                                        class="text-muted fw-bold" data-dz-name></a>
                                                                    <p class="mb-0" data-dz-size></p>
                                                                </div>
                                                                <div class="col-auto">
                                                                    <!-- Button -->
                                                                    <a href=""
                                                                        class="btn btn-link btn-lg text-muted"
                                                                        data-dz-remove>
                                                                        <i class="ri-close-line"></i>
                                                                    </a>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>

                                                <div class="text-danger files_err error_message"></div>

                                                
                                        </form>

                                </div>
                            </div> <!-- end row-->

                        </div>




                    </div> <!-- end card-body-->
                </div> <!-- end card-->
            </div> <!-- end col -->
        </div>
        <!-- end row-->

    </div> <!-- container -->
@endsection


@push('scripts')
    @vite(['resources/js/ui/component.fileupload.js','resources/js/hyper-syntax.js'])
@endpush
```

Here is the hyper-syntax.js where Dropzone is getting initialized.

```
import Dropzone from 'dropzone';

!function ($) {
    "use strict";

    var FileUpload = function () {
        this.$body = $("body")
    };


    /* Initializing */
    FileUpload.prototype.init = function () {
        // Disable auto discovery

        Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;

        $('[data-plugin="dropzone"]').each(function () {

            var actionUrl = $(this).attr('action')
            var previewContainer = $(this).data('previewsContainer');

            var csrfToken = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'); // Retrieve CSRF token from the meta tag

            var opts = { url: actionUrl, headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': csrfToken } }; // Add CSRF token to headers

            if (previewContainer) {
                opts['previewsContainer'] = previewContainer;
            }

            var uploadPreviewTemplate = $(this).data("uploadPreviewTemplate");
            if (uploadPreviewTemplate) {
                opts['previewTemplate'] = $(uploadPreviewTemplate).html();
            }

            var autoProcessQueue = $(this).data("autoProcessQueue");
            if (autoProcessQueue) {
                opts['autoProcessQueue'] = true; // Explicitly convert the string to a boolean
            } else {
                opts['autoProcessQueue'] = false; // Explicitly convert the string to a boolean
            }

            };

            var dropzoneEl = $(this).dropzone(opts);

        });
    },

        //init fileupload
        $.FileUpload = new FileUpload, $.FileUpload.Constructor = FileUpload

}(window.jQuery),

//initializing FileUpload
function ($) {
"use strict";
    $.FileUpload.init()
}(window.jQuery);
```

I tried attaching hyper-syntax.js in the app.blade.php and the page footer. But it seems to just not work no matter where I do it.